# MongoTemplate method or query for finding maximum values from a fileds

Tags: spring, mongodb

I am using MongoTemplate for my DB operations. Now i want to fetch the maximum fields values from the selected result. Can someone guide me how i write the query so that when i pass the query to find method it will return me the desired maximum fields of document . Thanks in advance
Regards

Comment: "maximum fields values" .. meaning? Paste maybe some code to make it more clear what do you need.

Comment: Here is the Complete Code...                                     public T findMaximumFields(Class c, String field) {

  T maxFieldDocs = null;
  Query query = new Query();
  query.with(new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, field)).limit(1);
  maxFieldDocs = (T) mongoTemplate.findOne(query, c);

  return maxFieldDocs;
 }

 public T findMinimumFields(Class c, String field) {

  T minFieldDocs = null;
  Query query = new Query();
  query.with(new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, field)).limit(1);
  minFieldDocs = (T) mongoTemplate.findOne(query, c);

  return minFieldDocs;
 }

Answer (score 5):

You can find "the object with the maximum field value" in spring-data-mongodb.  Mongo will optimize sort/limit combinations IF the sort field is indexed (or the @Id field).  Otherwise it is still pretty good because it will use a top-k algorithm and avoid the global sort ([mongodb sort doc)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/).  This is from [Mkyong's example](https://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/spring-data-mongodb-get-last-modified-records-date-sorting/) but I do the sort first and set the limit to one second.

```
Query query = new Query();
query.with(new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "idField"));
query.limit(1);
MyObject maxObject = mongoTemplate.findOne(query, MyObject.class);
```

Comment: Some versions can be: query.with(Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, "idField"));

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```
min = mongoTemplate.aggregate(
                        newAggregation(
                                group().min("_id").as("last")
                        ), "collection", Document.class)
                .getMappedResults().get(0).getLong("last", 0);

max = mongoTemplate.aggregate(
                        newAggregation(
                                group().max("_id").as("last")
                        ), "collection", Document.class)
                 .getMappedResults().get(0).getLong("last", 0);
```