# How to limit(1) record when sorting in descending order of date when passed in Query criteria of MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb

I am trying to create the below query on the basis of criteria.
The query is giving me results in descending order but limit(1) is not passed as part of query.

```
criteria.stream().forEach(c -> query.addCriteria(c).with(Sort.by(Direction.DESC, "creationDate")).limit(1));
```

How to pass the criteria to return only the first record from the sorted documents.

I have to apply the condition with query only . I cannot apply it at mongoTempate.find().
Please suggest a solution.

Comment: So there are multiple criteria I am passing these criteria in ArrayList and than adding them to query.addCriteria(), and passing this query to mongoTemplate.find(query.with(some Sort conditions)).

Comment: what is the problem with that?

Comment: The limit(1) is not working. In the ideal scenario this query should return only one document but its returning all documents .

Comment: this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16714694/mongotemplate-method-or-query-for-finding-maximum-values-from-a-fileds

Comment: @deadshot Thanks for replying, but its still returning all documents.

Comment: why are you applying sort to every criteria?